# most suitable OSGi platform?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, osgi

We are currently developing a new software for which we decided OSGi modularity would be quite useful, as the software itself can be pretty well decomposed into modular structure in order to avoid code mess in the future and be able to easily add new features and hook into existing ones.

I have been playing with two (probably most popular) OSGi platforms, Eclipse Equinox (with Gemini Blueprint) and Apache Felix (with Aries). Basically I am now at the point of making a decision, which one we should use.

We have pretty much experience with Spring, so we would like to continue using that, along with annotations (such as `@Autowired` for autowiring beans WITHIN the SAME bundle, `@ServiceReference` for autowiring across bundles), some particular Spring addons (such as Data JPA), Hibernate as a JPA provider (so far, we have experience only with Hibernate as an JPA implementation, it has all features we need so we want to avoid having to switch to something else), JMS messaging (with ActiveMQ client) and few other features.
Later on, we also want to be able to implement our own security manager (to control access to certain bundles, based on e.g. their digital signatures, certificates with Permissions embedded in them)

So far, I have been able to make two testing bundles (one was using a service from the other) and treat them as Spring Beans on Equinox with Gemini BP. However, I've had some problems with annotations, though (and I don't really like wiring beans in XMLs, especially with not so complicated architecture - most of them are Singletons).

I've tried Aries as well (but not succeeded with enabling Spring there; probably just haven't spent enough time on that yet :) ).

Which OSGi platform do you recommend for such use case?

Answer (score 6):

This one will be probably not the best answer but I think it is useful for you if I share my experiences. A couple of years ago I had exactly the same situation. I was experienced with Spring, JPA (Hibernate and EclipseLink). I found OSGi modularity useful so we started projects based on OSGi.

As I had used Spring before, it was obvious to use Blueprint (we ended up using Apache Aries as it was more stable than Gemini Blueprint). We did that for two years. However, we had many issues so I started to implement a new Blueprint container based on the specification. I heard many times that OSGi DS is better but as I had been a Spring fan before, the tutorials did not make me change my mind. I had the feeling that ConfigAdmin would have been really nice to use but with Blueprint it was not really possible to write nice code (I know that there is the cm namespace but it did not work well for us).

At the EclipseCon I talked to Peter Kriens and he convinced me to try out DS on a project. I did so and now I feel really sad about the time I used Blueprint (I did not mean to hurt you, Aries guys :)). Declarative Services together with ConfigurationAdmin is designed to work within the OSGi modularized world. I am pretty sure I know well your current feelings but if I really suggest to you not to make the same mistakes I did. Try to create two bundles with DS components, getting the Configuration from felix-configadmin and feel the power.

As of JPA, we used first EclipseLink. As it was too buggy, we switched to Hibernate. I wrote an adapter to be able to use it (available on GitHub). As much as I know, Hibernate has now more support in this topic, I have never tried it. In the end, we decided to leave JPA. We are on the end of replacing our infrastructure from JPA to Liquibase+QueryDSL. The components are more or less ready at https://github.com/everit-org, we need to work on documentation. If you are interested, why we switched from JPA, read the comments under the this blog post: http://blog.osgi.org/2013/12/attributes-attributes-and-attributes.html

My answer in short:

- If you want to avoid of using Declarative Services due to historical reasons (that is a mistake, but I can understand it), use Apache Aries or Gemini BP (that you find better). As Apache Aries was created for OSGi, all namespace handlers that are written for Aries will work for sure. Aries will not support the namespace handlers written for Spring as Aries has its own API. However, ActiveMQ and other projects have Aries namespace handler implementations. Once more, I suggest to consider using DS instead and write your code in Java instead of XML. If you design small modules, deployment time will not be a problem. On the other hand, you will get lots of benefits at the configuration and stability part.
- JPA with Hibernate can be used in OSGi. An example can be found here: https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-hibernate. More up-to-date examples are available if you google. I recommend that you should look around as JPA works, but it is not OSGi friendly.
- Concerning to the engine: If you use Felix, you can be sure that your code will run on other containers like Equinox or Knopflerfish. The other two has special features that if you use, you may run into the problem that you cannot port your code later. I personally use Equinox, but it has historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks for a really detailed reply. So you're suggesting to dump Spring altogether? What about using it for some other tasks (not as a dependency injector)? For example, Spring Data JPA provides really excellent ways to define your DAOs/repositories (as declarative interfaces), it would be really great if I could use that in my Data access bundle

Comment: I suggest that you should start with OSGi in the way as you can. Try out some tutorials about Declarative Services. If you do not see, how you could achieve your goals, move to Blueprint (probably Aries). However, keep in mind that you may change back later, when you had a couple of projects with OSGi. If you want an example that uses JPA and DS, you can check the enRoute example, written by Peter Kriens: https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.blog

Answer (score 5):

We use blueprint with [Apache aries](http://aries.apache.org/) a lot. Recently there were lots of bugs related to aries but most are fixed right now. Blueprint works pretty well for us but it is lacking a bit support for enterprise features compared to JavaEE. It has basic container managed transactions but little more on this side.

Declarative services seem to be more stable and light weight than blueprint. They also really embrace the dynamic nature of OSGi. On the other hand DS does not have any extension for e.g. JPA and container managed transactions. So I am not sure how difficult it is to write real business code with them.

I would be really careful with Gemini blueprint. Springsource seems to have completely abondoned OSGi. So I fear that Gemini blueprint will go the same  way as spring dm which is not maintained at all. Of course gemini is at eclipse now but I am not sure the community alone can support this.

In mid term I would really like to use CDI and the full JavaEE support on OSGi. There already is [pax cdi](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI) which provides support for CDI on OSGi and there are portable extensions for e.g. JPA and container managed transactions from [Apache Deltaspike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/). Unfortunately it is not yet fully working so as of now this is no real option.

So my recommendation is to currently do your own proof of concepts with Aries blueprint and DS and decide between the two. At the same time I would keep an eye open for JavaEE support on OSGi to see when it might be ready.

For the basic OSGi platform I think felix and equinox both are nice. It may also make sense to take a look at [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) which provides management and enterprise functionality on top of both frameworks.